# Quickr Service to manage the security restrictions of a document

Tags: lotus-domino

Is there a Quickr REST service (or QPAPI service) to manage the security restrictions of a document?

I have found services to manage the members and roles of a Place, but no one in a document per document basis.

Answer (score 0):

That API is not currently publicly available.  The public Quickr APIs are documented [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lqwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=API%20Documentation).